# when i storing date in firebase by react native with this way it doesn't saved and only cart Items and total Amount only saved in the firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, date, storing-information

[when I store the date in firebase by react native  with this way it doesn't save and only cart Items and total Amount only saved in the firebase how can I solve this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/322HK.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: `toISOString` is a method, so you need to put parentheses (`()`) behind it to invoke the method: `const date = new Date().toISOString();`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.